# .NET C# Bundle Directory of files into console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Background** 
I have a C# solution that has a few projects inside it, the file structure looks like this.

```
Solution
- Jobs
  - myWebJob
- Presentation
  - MyMVCProject
    - Areas 
      - Reports
        - Multiple files inside here
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish** 
When I build my webjob I want the build to essentially bundle/include the Areas/Reports/Files with it so I have those to reference in my webjob. Is that possible?

**What I've tried** 
I added a reference to MyMVCProject and can get to the Areas folder but that's all the further I can go, I don't have access to the Reports/Files directory.

Answer (score 0):

Think I actually figured it out from this article :

https://andrewlock.net/including-linked-files-from-outside-the-project-directory-in-asp-net-core/

All I did was go to the folder I wanted my files in, in this case its the Reports folder. I right clicked and went to Add Existing Item, navigated to the files I wanted linked(inside my MVCProject) and highlighted them. Instead of clicking the Add Button, I clicked Add As Link. This added a link to those files so anytime they are updated, they will update in my webjob project.